# Custom post type doesn't display on admin list

Tags: custom-post-types, admin

I have a custom post type, list, with 86 posts, none of which show up on the list for its admin page.  It just says "List not found".  But when I choose "October 2015" from the filter dropdown, all the posts display.  Another post type, which is defined in the same way, has the expected display of those posts.  Any ideas?

Here's the custom post definition:

```
function custom_post_list() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                => 'Lists',
    'singular_name'       => 'List',
    'menu_name'           => 'Lists',
    'name_admin_bar'      => 'List',
    'parent_item_colon'   => 'Parent Item:',
    'all_items'           => 'All Lists',
    'add_new_item'        => 'Add New List',
    'add_new'             => 'Add New List',
    'new_item'            => 'New List',
    'edit_item'           => 'Edit List',
    'update_item'         => 'Update List',
    'view_item'           => 'View List',
    'search_items'        => 'Search Lists',
    'not_found'           => 'List not found',
    'not_found_in_trash'  => 'Not found in Trash',
);
$args = array(
    'label'               => 'list',
    'description'         => 'A list of posts with something in common',
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ),
    'taxonomies'          => array( 'post_tag' ),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-list-view',
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
);
register_post_type( 'list', $args );
```

Comment: Is `list` one of the reserved terms for WP?

Comment: @jdm2112 [It doesn't look like it](https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms) but it wouldn't hurt to change it from `list` to something really unique to see if that helps.

Comment: Please go Settings > Permalink and click Save button once.